# css errors main menu

Tags: drush, theming

I have  this error with my css, what drush commands I can use to fix this? is it a permissions fix?[image]
please guide me step by step

Answer (score 0):

You provide very little information ... Which version of Drupal? (It's Drupal 7 based on the paths.) Which theme have you just enabled causing this problem? It worked before you switched theme, right?

My best guess: You have installed a theme that is a subtheme of Bootstrap without installing the Bootstrap theme itself.